# Random script using bash

Tags: bash, scripts

I'm trying to write a random script bash, but I'm having some problems.
In a directory "quotations" there are some files that I'd like to access randomly, but every time I try it I get the following error:

`cat: '/home/thomas/Store/quotations/.': Is a directory`

Here's the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
targetDir="/home/thomas/Store/quotations/"
files=( "$targetDir"/.* )
index="$RANDOM"
while [ "$index" -ge ${#files[@]} ]; do
    index=${RANDOM:4:4}
done
cat "${files[$index]}"
```

I'd appreciate some help.

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

There are two special directories in every directory that your wildcard matches: `.` and `..`. Are you sure you didn't want `"$targetDir"/*` instead? You'd need to filter out directories, anyway.

You can use

```
[[ -d $filename ]]
```

to test whether the filename is a directory.

Also, the usual way to turn $RANDOM into a number in the interval 0 - $n, you can use

```
index=$(( RANDOM % (n + 1) ))
```

where % is the modulus operator.

In other words:

```
#!/bin/bash
targetDir=/home/thomas/Store/quotations
files=( "$targetDir"/* )
index=$(( RANDOM % ${#files[@]} ))
until [[ -f ${files[index]} ]] ; do 
    index=$(( RANDOM % ${#files[@]} ))
done
cat "${files[index]}"
```

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly now ! 
Guess i need to train more :)